# How to support my app in Citrix MDM solution

Tags: ios, mdm, citrix

I have application on App store. I want to add support for Citrix MDM solution, which will allow end user to install application as in-office app.

Want to know what are the steps I need to perform in application?

I have gone through the details on [citrix](https://www.citrix.com/) and got following information in bits and pieces and have some question on top of information

1. Need to use the [MAM SDK](https://developer.cloud.com/device-management) in iOS app. From where I should Download the SDK? Is it freely available for POC purpose?
2. If I integrate the SDK what are the changes I need to do in application? any sample application available?
3. Need to [wrap the iOS application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZrMzMH4O1E) . Is it required if I use MAM SDK?
4. My application communicate with my server and has user authentication. Do I need to change anything on my server?
5. Is dummy/temporary server setup of Citrix is available to test my application?

Answer (score 0):

Let me tackle each question.

1. You'll want to download the [MAM SDK](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-endpoint-management/product-software/mdx-toolkit.html) from the citrix.com web site.  To do so though you'll need to first create a user account.  It is free to download.
2. The changes to your iOS app are fairly straightforward.  I won't repeat them here, but in the MAM SDK download you'll find step-by-step instructions on what you need to do.  There is a sample app with source code provided.
3. You no longer need to MDX Wrap your iOS application.  That's the older way of getting your apps managed by Citrix Endpoint Management.  The new MAM SDK approach replaces that mechanism.
4. There are no changes needed to your authentication.
5. There's no dummy server available, but you can request a trial site.  Create an account at [Citrix Cloud](https://onboarding.cloud.com/) and request a trial of Endpoint Management.

Source: I'm an engineer for the Citrix Endpoint Management product.